# How to download data from server using date in get methos React?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, get, axios, fetch

I'm new with React. I was looking for information for several days to no avail. So I decided to ask you my stupid question.

I have problem with transforming date from `DatePicker` to date format which than I can use in get request.
I use DatePicker from this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Sample correct api call:

```
localhost:8080/api/measurement/12374?date=2020-12-13 12:00
```

but date from DatePicker look like:

```
Sun Dec 13 2020 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

I play with date for example:

```
let x = new Date();
let x1 = x.toLocaleDateString() + " " + x.toLocaleTimeString();
output: 23/12/2020 09:29:16
```

but still I have problem with date format and I also don't know how to pass this date correclty to get method, because http request have `%` instead `"space"`

```
http://localhost:8080/api/measurement/12120?date=23/12/2020%2009:48:15
```

but when I use string as date it work fine and download data:

```
let value = "12374";
let date = "2020-12-13 12:00";
const request = "http://localhost:8080/api/measurement/" + value + "?date=" + date;
```

Can someone explain me how can I convert date from DatePicker to format like this `2020-12-13 12:00` and then use it in get method?

I will be very grateful for any answer!
Thank you ;)

Comment: which date picker are you using

Comment: @newbie I use it from this page https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use momentjs for this task to format date.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

```
import moment from 'moment'

let date = new Date();
let result = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm')
```

output: 23/12/2020 02:23